# how to get hanging instructions of a dll using IDApython

Tags: idapython, dll

I need to get hanging instructions i.e instructions which are not under any functions in a dll through idapython script? it is available in brown color when seen through IDA pro.

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution will be to iterate over every instruction in the code and check if it is inside a function.

Using [Sark](http://sark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
for line in sark.lines():
    if not line.is_code:
        # The line is not a code line, so we skip it.
        continue
    if sark.is_function(line.ea):
        # Line is inside a function, skip it.
        continue

    # The line is code outside a function. Print it.
    print line
```

Using standard IDAPython

```
import idaapi
import idc

def iter_all_lines():
    start = idaapi.cvar.inf.minEA
    end = idaapi.cvar.inf.maxEA

    item = idaapi.get_item_head(start)
    while item < end:
        yield item
        item += idaapi.get_item_size(item)


def iter_hanging_lines():
    for line in iter_all_lines():
        if not idaapi.isCode(idaapi.getFlags(line)):
            # The line is not a code line, so we skip it.
            continue

        if idaapi.get_func(line):
            # The line is inside a function, skip it.
            continue

        # The line is code outside a function. Yield it.
        yield line


for line in iter_handing_lines():
    print "[{:08X}]    {}".format(line, idc.GetDisasm(line))
```

Comment: i dont want to use other lib . is it possible with idapython api itself ?

Comment: Updated the answer to match. But @w-s gave a much better answer. I was not aware of that API.

Comment: You can use idautils.Heads(minea,maxea) instead of iter_all_lines, it should give similar functionality

Answer (score 1):

This command will find the address if hanging instruction next to the ScreenEA() and print it.

```
import idaapi
import idc
addr = idaapi.find_not_func(ScreenEA(), 1)
if addr != idc.BADADDR: 
    print "0x%08x : %s" % (addr, idc.GetDisasm(addr))
else:
    print "Hanging instruction not found"
```

To print all the hanging instructions in the loaded binary, do the following:

```
import idaapi
import idc
addr = idaapi.find_not_func(0, 1)
while addr != idc.BADADDR:
    print "0x%08x : %s" % (addr, idc.GetDisasm(addr))
    addr = idaapi.find_not_func(addr, 1)
print "No more hanging instruction found"
```

Comment: I want the exact instruction itself not address

Comment: Updated an answer